# Use external mail program with IMSCP/I-MSCP Mail Server

Tags: web-hosting

I created an email account in the IMSCP customer area. You can only enter a username and a password. The email adress is then usernaime@domain.de.
However I can not find the adresses of smtp and imap servers and the settings and ports regarding encryption. Can someone help me? (I think this is sth. that should be shown in the interface, can not understand why it is not printed there...)